# How to slice TimeSeries data?

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data, time-series

When retrieving curated data, v10 now returns `TimeSeries` objects.

For example,

```
ts = WeatherData["KP60", "Temperature", {{2013, 7, 1}, {2013, 9, 30}}]

DateListPlot[ts]
```

What is the most convenient way to extract a range from this temporal data, for example for plotting purposes?  E.g. only plot the first two weeks of August from this data.

I know I can simply convert it to a list using `Normal` and then use e.g. `Select` to filter.  Is there anything better?

Comment: Congratulations on being our [foremost question poster!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/146/socratic)

Comment: WeatherData fails when I try w/ 10.0.1: `ibraryFunction::versint: The version number 1 of the library is from a previous WolframLibrary that cannot support integers as large as 4472425792`. Anyone else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the new operations on `TimeSeries` objects is `TimeSeriesWindow`. I think it does what you need.

```
ts = WeatherData["KP60", "Temperature", {{2013, 7, 1}, {2013, 9, 30}}];
DateListPlot[TimeSeriesWindow[ts, {{2013, 8, 1}, {2013, 8, 14}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I get the results back into a TimeSeries?  It's returning a different format causing subsequent errors in code that expects a TimeSeries.

Comment: @Michael, the TimeSeriesWindow argument to DateListPlot will be a TimeSeries. You might be using the DateListPlot output which is not a TimeSeries.

Comment: I'm actually using the output of FinancialData

Comment: I'm not sure what to say without more information. I do know that TimeSeriesWindow will return a TimeSeries when used as documented.